# Date range comparisons in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have two panda data frames in python. dataframe1 contains the sample data.

```
      lat        long      tep  height  altitude      date_time        
  40.007647  116.319781    0   83  39688.535613  2008-08-20 12:51:17   
  40.007632  116.319878    0  119  39688.535637  2008-08-20 12:51:19   
  40.007615  116.319838    0  112  39688.535660  2008-08-20 12:51:21
```

Dataframe 2 contains the following sample data.

```
Start_Time                   End_Time               Transportation_Mode
2008-08-20 12:09:17     2008-08-20 12:45:05                walk
2008-08-20 12:45:05     2008-08-20 13:00:25              subway
2008-08-20 13:00:25     2008-08-20 13:07:25                walk
2008-08-20 13:07:25     2008-08-20 13:12:59                 bus
2008-08-20 13:13:59     2008-08-20 13:24:23                walk
```

Dataframe1 should pick transportation mode from dataframe2 based on the condition, if data_time field in dataframe1 lies in between `Start_Time` and `End_Time` field of dataframe 2. Then pick Transportation_mode from dataframe2 and attach with `Tranportation_Mode` in dataframe1.

End result should look like this

```
  lat        long      tep  height  altitude      date_time        Transportation_Mode
40.007647  116.319781    0   83  39688.535613  2008-08-20 12:51:17   subway   
40.007632  116.319878    0  119  39688.535637  2008-08-20 12:51:19   subway   
40.007615  116.319838    0  112  39688.535660  2008-08-20 12:51:21   subway
```

Its equivalent sql statement is

```
select distinct df1.*, df2.Transportation_Mode   
from df1,df2   
where df1.date_time between df2.Start_Time and df2.End_Time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[merge_asof](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) can help you here

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='date_time', right_on='Start_Time')
```

results in:

> ```
>   lat     long    tep     height  altitude    date_time   Start_Time  End_Time    Transportation_Mode
> 0     40.007647   116.319781  0   83  39688.535613    2008-08-20 12:51:17     2008-08-20 12:45:05     2008-08-20 13:00:25     subway
> 1     40.007632   116.319878  0   119     39688.535637    2008-08-20 12:51:19     2008-08-20 12:45:05     2008-08-20 13:00:25     subway
> 2     40.007615   116.319838  0   112     39688.535660    2008-08-20 12:51:21     2008-08-20 12:45:05     2008-08-20 13:00:25     subway
> ```

This only looks at the `Start_Time`. If you want to check the `End_Time` too you can do something like this:

```
start = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='date_time', right_on='Start_Time')['Transportation_Mode']
end = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='date_time', right_on='End_Time', direction='forward')['Transportation_Mode']

pd.concat((df1, start[start == end].reindex(df1.index)), axis=1)
```

> ```
>   lat     long    tep     height  altitude    date_time   Transportation_Mode
> 0     40.007647   116.319781  0   83  39688.535613    2008-08-20 12:51:17     subway
> 1     40.007632   116.319878  0   119     39688.535637    2008-08-20 12:51:19     subway
> 2     40.007615   116.319838  0   112     39688.535660    2008-08-20 12:51:21     subway
> ```

## without `direction`

If you can't use pandas > 0.20 You could try this:

```
start = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='date_time', right_on='Start_Time')
transportation_mode = start['Transportation_Mode'].loc[(start['Start_Time'] < start['date_time']) & (start['date_time'] < start['End_Time'])]
pd.concat((df1, transportation_mode), axis=1)
```

> ```
>   lat     long    tep     height  altitude    date_time   Transportation_Mode
> 0     40.007647   116.319781  0   83  39688.535613    2008-08-20 12:51:17     subway
> 1     40.007632   116.319878  0   119     39688.535637    2008-08-20 12:51:19     subway
> 2     40.007615   116.319838  0   112     39688.535660    2008-08-20 12:51:21     subway
> 3894  40.088452   116.306029  0   177     39680.677581    2008-08-20 16:15:43     NaN
> 3895  40.088434   116.306011  0   178     39680.677604    2008-08-20 16:15:45     NaN
> 3896  40.088423   116.306002  0   179     39680.677627    2008-08-20 16:15:47     NaN
> 3897  40.088405   116.305990  0   179     39680.677650    2008-08-20 16:15:49     NaN
> 3898  40.088387   116.305963  0   180     39680.677674    2008-08-20 16:15:51     NaN
> ```

Comment: I have tried but this does not work. its not picking right transportation mode. my desired result in sql is 
select distinct df1.*, df2.Transportation_Mode
from df1,df2
where df1.date_time between df2.Start_Time and df2.End_Time

Comment: If this still doesn't work, give a sample dataset which fails

Comment: How to give you sample data? its very big takes too much space here to copy and paste.

Comment: You don't have to give the complete data, just a subset which shows unwanted behaviour

Comment: lat     long    tep     height  altitude    date_time   Transportation_Mode
3894 40.088452 116.306029 0 177 39680.677581 2008-08-20 16:15:43 2008-08-20 16:15:43
3895 40.088434 116.306011 0 178 39680.677604 2008-08-20 16:15:45 2008-08-20 16:15:45
3896 40.088423 116.306002 0 179 39680.677627 2008-08-20 16:15:47 2008-08-20 16:15:47
3897 40.088405 116.305990 0 179 39680.677650 2008-08-20 16:15:49 2008-08-20 16:15:49
3898 40.088387 116.305963 0 180 39680.677674 2008-08-20 16:15:51 2008-08-20 16:15:51

here transportation mode should be null, because date_time doesn't lie in any range.

Comment: your updated code is giving this error  
TypeError: merge_asof() got an unexpected keyword argument 'direction'

Comment: from the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) `direction : ‘backward’ (default), ‘forward’, or ‘nearest’

    Whether to search for prior, subsequent, or closest matches.

    New in version 0.20.0.
`

Comment: I am using python version 2.7.13, is this the version problem?

Comment: the version of pandas is the problem, not so much the python version. I added something that should work without the `direction` attribute